# Why is setUpClass(cls): executed several times?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-3.x, visual-studio-2013

I'm implementing component tests for a web service. I want to use the class method `setUpClass(cls):` to start my web service only once in the beginning, however `setUpClass(cls):` is executed before each of my test cases. Why? The documentation says it is executed only once before the test cases are executed. Any ideas?
I'm using Python 3.5.

```
class SomeTest(unittest.TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.MyService = ComponentManager.GetMyService()
        cls.MyService.Start()
        return super(SomeTest, cls).setUpClass()

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        return super(SomeTest, cls).tearDownClass()

    def test_invalid_request(self):
        response = self.client.SendJSONRequest(Constants.METHOD_POST, '/tile/invalid/', '{}')
        ...
```

Comment: can you add a test case please?

Comment: What test runner are you using? Is that test runner executing tests in concurrently at all?

Comment: @wind85: I added a test case. All my test cases look like that. (always starting with test_)

Comment: @Javiator shoudn't be using the setUp() method?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I have no clue. I'm using VS 2013 and Anaconda 3. Where can I see which test runner I'm using?

Comment: So how do you run the tests?

Comment: @wind85 No. setUp() is executed once before each test case, setUpClass() is only executed before all test cases once

Comment: @MartijnPieters Using the text execution engine of Visual Studio. I have Python tools for VS 2013 installed.

Comment: @Javiator: well, that's a custom test runner; it looks like that test runner is running your tests in isolation, probably concurrently, and it is *that runner* that is causing the class setup and teardown to be called for each test.

Comment: @MartijnPieters So how do I fix this? Which test runner should I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [Python tools for Visual Studio source code](https://github.com/Microsoft/PTVS/blob/master/Python/Product/TestAdapter/TestExecutor.cs#L98-L284), the VS test runner runs each test case *entirely in isolation*.

Each test case is run as a separate command-line invocation of the Python interpreter (using a [custom test launcher](https://github.com/Microsoft/PTVS/blob/master/Python/Product/TestAdapter/visualstudio_py_testlauncher.py), passing in the module and test name for each), which is why the class setup and teardown are called for each test. Python is never given the opportunity to run these tests together.

If this matters to you, you'll have to [file a ticket with the Python Tools project](https://github.com/Microsoft/PTVS/issues); I see no [relevant open ticket for the test adapter](https://github.com/Microsoft/PTVS/labels/Test%20Adapter) at this time.

Alternatively, run your tests with a different test runner. You could use the [built-in `unittest` command line](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#command-line-interface), for example:

```
python3 -m unittest your_package
```

or pick any of the [popular tools available](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/tests/#tools).